# How to make Angular 2 support ÆØÅ characthers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, character-encoding

Im trying to list an array with words that contains ÆØÅ characthers. I can list the array with an *for* loop and the words that are in the array comes out, but cannot display ÆØÅ characthers - a questionmark is shown instead. The array is of type `string[]`

I`ve tried adding an meta tag with charset="utf-8" to the head section of my index.html file, but this dosent seem to help.

Is there anything else i might try to make ÆØÅ work with Angular 2, there shouldn`t be any problem by adding words that contains æøå to an array?

**Html file where i loop over the array**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let heatingType of heatingTypes; let i=index">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{ i }}" class="form-control" 
                       formControlName="heating" [checked]="heating.indexOf(heatingType) > -1" 
                       (click)="toggleSelection(heatingType)">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
                <label for="heating">{{ heatingType }}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>Some app</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('src/app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <span class="apploader">
            Laster inn applikasjonen<br />
            Vennligst vent ...
        </span>
    </app>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Array**

```
heatingTypes: string[] = [
    'Elektriske ovner', 'Varmepumpe', 'Vannbåren varme',
    'Varmekabler', 'Sentralfyr/Fjernvarme', 'Vedfyring', 'Annet'
];
```

[Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOPVF.png)

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me with a quick test. Can you post some of your code so we can get a better understanding of what you are working with?

Comment: Sure, I`ve updated the question desc now.

Comment: Are those characters shown normally if you add them directly in HTML? Make sure that your website is not outputting a different charset in headers.

Comment: Yes, æøå characthers are shown normally in HTML. I just copied the same code - the html content with the for loop and the array - to an another component, and there its shows the words correctly.. thats weird, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have meta tag set make sure the HTML file is saved in UTF-8 format as well, some editors save files in different encodings (like Sublime for Mac OS X). To verify do following

1. Open the file in Notepad
2. Click on save as and see the encoding selected below filetype. If it's ASCII or something else change it to UTF-8 and save the file and reload, it should work fine.

Comment: well, i`ve tried that now and it still dosent work. I just deleted the file, and added the entire code to Notepad - to clean the formatting - , then created a new file (with the same content) with utf-8 as encoding, and copied the code from notepad to the newly created html file. But the problem remains... I`m using Visual Studio 2017 btw.

Comment: Are you facing this issue in your local or in server after pushing changes to TFS ? If you have pushed changes to TFS and facing issues with file pushed to server from TFS then go to source control and select file -> right click -> click on advanced and check what is encoding set in properties.

Comment: So, it works now then. I removed the word "Vannbåren varme" from the array and rewrote it. Its seems that the encoding on that current word had not been updated. Thanks anyway! I will try this solution next time I get into the same problem.